# Android: How to connect Spinner selection with AutoCompleteTextView

Tags: android, dynamic, onclick, android-spinner, autocompletetextview

I'm trying to connect actions in Spinner with AutoCompleteTextView. My goal is when user selects some item in spinner, AutoCompleteTextView suggestion list needs to be changed.

Example:

**Spinner items:** Cats, Dogs, Horses

**String1:** cat1, cat2, cat3, ...

**String2:** dog1, dog2, dog3, ...

**String3:** horse1, horse2, horse3 ...

So when user chooses 'Dogs' in spinner and after that clicks on AutoCompleteTextView, he will get following suggestions after he begins to write: dog1, dog2, dog3. Similar for Cats and Horses.

I can't find a solution for this problem.

I tried to put onClickListener to AutoCompleteTextView but it seems that doesn't work.

```
autoCompleteTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
//some actions
});
```

And there should be some better solution because after the screen opens that AutoCompleteTextView is already selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the API for AutoCompleteTextView - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html

The suggestions are populated from a data adapter, so you could modify the data adapter for your autoCOmpleteTextView after the user makes their spinner selection:

```
mySpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) 
    {
          String[] choices; 
          // set the adapter for the autoCOmpleteTextView here based on what was selected
          if(DOGS) {
                choices = new String[] {"dog1", "dog2", "dog3"};
          } else if (CATS) {
                choices = new String[] {"cat1", "cat2", "cat3"};
          }
          // etc...
          ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
             android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, choices);
             myTextView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) 
    {
         // nothing
    }
});
```

Comment: It's working! Only thing that needs to be changed in adapter constructor is to put 'NameOfTheActivity.this' instead of only 'this'. ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(NameOfTheActivity.this,
             android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, choices);
             myTextView.setAdapter(adapter);